# How to set the height of the contents of a tab content to auto

Tags: css, materialize

The tabs in materialize.css seems to allow content spanning only upto a certain height beyond which it just seems to chop it off.

How can I change this so that irrespective of how long each of the tab content is it doesn't chop it off and lets it expand downwards as much as it wants?

```
<ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs">
  <li class="tab col s3">
    <a href="#test-swipe-1">Test 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab col s3">
    <a class="active" href="#test-swipe-2">Test 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab col s3">
    <a href="#test-swipe-3">Test 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="test-swipe-1" class="col s12 blue">Test 1</div>
<div id="test-swipe-2" class="col s12 red">Test 2</div>
<div id="test-swipe-3" class="col s12 green">Test 3</div>
```

I don't want any of the tab content height to be dependant on the other. They should expand only as much necessary.

Comment: Can you share a fiddle with your CSS included? Thanks

Comment: That actually worked! I tried to do the same in codepen and could not replicate the bug. So redid the entire thing and deleted all the code that had anything to do with carousel. Somehow though there was no carousel in my page the carousel-item somehow got added to the ul. No idea how. So deleting that solved my problem. Thank you.